# Differential Equation: Substitution of argument

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to use the substitution $x=\cosh{t}$ to simplify the coefficients of this differential equation:

$$-\ddot{y}-\:\coth(t)\:\:\dot{y}\:+\:\left(20+\frac{4}{\sinh ^2(t)}\right)y=0$$

> **Remark from problem:** Assume the first solution to be a polynomial of maximum degree 6 and consider the initial condition $\:y'(0)=0$.

If I do it I get:

$$t=arccosh(x)\:;\:\:\:\:\ \frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{\cosh ^2t-1}=\sinh t$$

Which leads to:
$$\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dx}\:\frac{dx}{dt}=\sinh t\:y'$$
$$\ddot{y}=\frac{dy}{dt}\left(\sinh t\right)\cdot y'+\sinh t\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left(y'\right)\:\frac{dx}{dt}=\cosh t\cdot y'+\sinh ^2t\cdot y''$$

Pluging into the equation and reducing, I get:

$$-\sinh ^2t\cdot \:y''-2\cosh \:t\cdot \:y'+\left(20+\frac{4}{\sinh ^2t}\right)y=0$$

Which clearly is not a simplified equation neither a common form for me to solve directly (or maybe I don't see it).

> Could you please help me to review if I'm doing something wrong and give me a hint to solve the final differential equation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

Your equation is correct : $\quad-\sinh ^2t\cdot \:y''-2\cosh \:t\cdot \:y'+\left(20+\frac{4}{\sinh ^2t}\right)y=0$

But the change of variable isn't completed : the equation must not contain the variable $t$, but only the variable $x$.

Then, it is possible to simplify even more. One observe that the change of $x$ to $-x$ doesn't change the ODE. This draw us to the new change of variable $X=x^2$.

Then by inspection, it seems valuable to try a simple polynomial solution. In fact, a solution is obtained on the form of a quadratic function.

A second independent solution could certainly be obtained, with order reduction of the ODE thanks to the variation of parameter method. But this seems a bit too boring for me. So, I let you continue, if you really need the general solution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood your steps. However, I wonder if you could explain the last step when you find the solution $y=c_1(X-1)(7X-1)$ because I can't see it clearly.

Comment: In trying $y=ax^2+bx+c$ : Put it in the ODE and identify the coefficients.